# How to get minLength in @Size when generating code from jOOQ?

Tags: jooq

Google is failing me ...

What steps are required so jOOQ code generation will not only set (max = nnn) on the @Size validation annotation, but also a (min = nn)? Setting a CHECK on Postgres doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a reliable way to specify the minimum length of a varchar data type in SQL, which can be picked up by a client like jOOQ's code generator. Sure, you can define a check constraint as follows:

```sql
CHECK (LENGTH (my_column) BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
```

But in order to figure out the semantics of this check constraint, jOOQ would need to parse the SQL string and recognise all sorts of built-in functions and expression. E.g. the following check constraint is equivalent to the above:

```sql
CHECK (LENGTH (my_column) + 1 BETWEEN 11 AND 3 * 7)
```

And then, there are subtle variations that cannot be expressed using the `@Size` validation annotation, such as:

```sql
CHECK (LENGTH (TRIM (my_column)) BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
```

Or even

```sql
CHECK (LENGTH (my_column) + LENGTH (my_other_column) BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
```

Of course, you can hard code some rules into your own custom code generator extension. The code generator has check constraint information available and you can hook into the methods that are called to generate these annotations, so this will definitely work for your specific case.

Comment: Thanks, @lukas-eder. I finally got round to implementing this (specific to my case, ie postgresql + char_length > n). The source is on [github](https://github.com/sniederb/funneltravel-public/blob/master/funnel-server/src/main/java/ch/want/funnel/services/persistence/jooqextension/JavaGeneratorWithMinLength.java)